# generate many components from an array

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I have an array and I need to generate many components as the array lengh:
I tried this but it didn't worked:

```
let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"];
let itemList = [];
items.forEach((item, index) => {
    itemList.push(<li key={index}>{item}</li>);
});
export default function TaskList(props) {
    return (
        <div className="task-list-container">
            <Task id="" nombre={itemList} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

So I need one component from TaskList that contains Item1 and other Item2 and so one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not very clear what you're trying to do...

But I think you should try to loop in the render part instead of stacking components in variables ...

```
let items=['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4','Item 5'];
export default function TaskList(props) {
      return (
            <div className="task-list-container">
                {
                  items.map((item, index) => <Task key={index} value={item} />)
                }
            </div>
      )
}
```

It will render as many `<Task>` components as string in the `items` array

Comment: The `key` should be `{index}` and not the string `"{index}"`.